# How about select some element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given an array like this:

```
a = [{id:1, name:'a'}, {id:2, name:'b'}, {id:3, name:'c'}, {id:4, name:'d'}, {id:5, name:'e'}];

b = ['a','d'];

c = [1,4];
```

How I get c from a and b? I want to get id from name. Thank u.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `.map` and `.find`:

```js
const a = [{id:1, name:'a'},{id:2, name:'b'}, {id:3, name:'c'},{id:4, name:'d'},{id:5, name:'e'}];
const b = ['a','d'];

const c = b.map(findName => 
  a.find(({ name }) => name === findName)
    .id
);
console.log(c);
```

You could also transform the input array into an object indexed by name, and then just `map` over the names, so as not to require a `.find` every time:

```js
const a = [{id:1, name:'a'},{id:2, name:'b'}, {id:3, name:'c'},{id:4, name:'d'},{id:5, name:'e'}];
const b = ['a','d'];

const obj = a.reduce((accum, { id, name }) => {
  accum[name] = id;
  return accum;
}, {});
const c = b.map(name => obj[name]);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
b.forEach(itemB => {
  c.push(a.find(x=> x.name === itemB).id);
});
```

Loop thru b array and try to `find` it in array `a`, if exist, push the id into `c`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [{id:1, name:'a'},{id:2, name:'b'},
        {id:3, name:'c'},{id:4, name:'d'},{id:5, name:'e'}];

const b = ['a','d'];

const c = a.filter(function(item){
  return b.indexOf(item.name) !== -1
}).map(function(item){
  return item.id
});

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
var d = a.filter((item)=>{
   return b.indexOf(item.name) >= 0;
}); 
var c =  d.map((item) => {
  return item.id;
 });
// Result = [1,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Please try this one*

```js
a = [ { id: 1, name: 'a' },
  { id: 2, name: 'b' },
  { id: 3, name: 'c' },
  { id: 4, name: 'd' },
  { id: 5, name: 'e' } ]
  
  b = ['a','d'];
  c = []
    a.map(res => { if (b.includes(res.name)) { c.push(res.id) } });
    alert(c)
```